# How does the service module work?

Tags: 8

i am using drupal 6 and services 6.3x module but i am unable to use this module completely.
I have enabled rest server module also.
I added a new service and added resources to it.
I added node resource to it and i am able to fetch all the nodes in json format

what i am not able to understand is :-

1. The exact uri or may be the procedure to call getTree method in taxonomy_vocabulary resource
2. How to acccess all the methods (CRUD) functions under every resource enabled
3. The url -> mydomain.com/service/rest/node.json works for me but how can i access the getTree method ??

I am stuck on this like forever i have even posted jobs on the drupal site but i guess there are very rare people who have knowledge about this.

**Edit :-**

Live link is http://delvelogic.com/merchant/drupal-6.22/services/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary

The following is the java code i am using :-

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;  
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://delvelogic.com/merchant/drupal-6.22/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree.json");
    postMethod.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    postMethod.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
  //  postMethod.addHeader("Authorization", "basic " + Base64.encodeBytes(("admin"+":"+"admin123").getBytes()));
 //   httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT));

     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vid", ""+1));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parent", ""+1));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("maxdepth",""+1));
    // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair())
    try{
     postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
     response = httpClient.execute(postMethod); 

     InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input),input.toString().length());
     String line;
     StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
     }
     rd.close();
     uploadresponse = sb.toString();

     Log.d("Response", ""+uploadresponse);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also if there is any firefox add on so that i can actually see the method working ??

**Edit Again :-**

I have found this add on restclient to work on firefox

i choose the method as post
in the url i typed http://delvelogic.com/merchant/drupal-6.22/services/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree

added header :-

Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept : application/json

request body :-

&vid=1&parent=1&maxdepth=1

it gives me 404 not found with no vocabulary with id 1 found
Thanks in advance

Comment: i pledge if i get this thing completely solved i will make a screencast for dumb people like me so that they dnt stuck up :P this module needs much resources

Comment: check the edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the URLs shouldn't necessarily have .json at the end, but I guess this is a setting you've changed if it's working for the node functions. I know you're not going to like this answer (I'm fairly certain you've tried it before) but the URL is: `mydomain.com/service/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree`. I've even been through the service and rest_server modules' respective code and that is definitely what it should be.

For further proof look at the (valid, passed) test module for services taxonomy_vocabulary:

[ServicesResourceTaxonomyTests::testVocabularyGetTree](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--services--tests--functional--ServicesResourceTaxonomyTests.test/function/ServicesResourceTaxonomyTests%3A%3AtestVocabularyGetTree/7).

You'll see that the URLs accessed by this successfully passed test are: `$path . '/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree'`, where `$path` is the path to the endpoint (i.e. `mymodule.com/service/rest/`).

It really would help if you could provide a live link though so we can test to see if the problem is in your Java code or with Drupal (although the latter seems very unlikely).

EDIT

p.s. do comment on this answer as I have a lot of experience with the services module and I'm sure I can point you in the right direction with a bit more info. It pains me to see someone struggling with something that I've had nothing but joy with in the past!

ANOTHER EDIT

This is the response I get from `http://delvelogic.com/merchant/drupal-6.22/services/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <result>
    <nodes/>
    <module>taxonomy</module>
    <name></name>
    <help></help>
    <relations>0</relations>
    <hierarchy>0</hierarchy>
    <multiple>0</multiple>
    <required>0</required>
    <tags>0</tags>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <vid>4</vid>
  </result>
```

Notice the `<vid>4</vid>` bit...I'm pretty sure the `vid` you should be looking for is `4`, not `1`!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. i have edited my question and added the live link and my android code.... the link you provided is giving me null http://delvelogic.com/merchant/drupal-6.22/services/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree

Comment: you can check the edit now

Comment: hey clive... is this a multipart data ??? should i send it in multipart??

Comment: Sorry for delay, I don't think it does need to be multipart, no. I've got a bit of time now so I'll have a quick play with the modules in question and get back to you soon

Comment: not as in u owe me a solution but wud be nice to have it :)

Comment: lol don't worry about it :) Sorry to ask the most ridiculous of questions, but are you 100% sure there's a vocabulary with a `vid` of 1?? Judging from the response `no vocabulary with id 1 found` it might be worth double checking the `vocabulary` table in your Drupal install just to be certain. I'm currently getting a `406` response (not `404`) with "Missing required argument vid", will report back when I manage to make the connection

Comment: yes i dont know why this response comes since i have vid 1 for a particular vocabulary u can check services/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary for that purpose

Comment: Think I've found the problem check the updated answer :)

Comment: did u check with vid 4?? plus how are you checking?? are you using my code above?? is it a right code??

Comment: are you using rest client or poster on firefox??

Comment: ok now i have started with a fresh install you can check a new link http://delvelogic.com/infra2/drupal-6.19/services/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree and i use rest client in firefox when i use Post in method type i get unsupported request content type while if i use GET then i get status 200 code i get this in response body <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result></result>
with Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded and Accept : application/json as parameters in header

Comment: just cant get it working :(

Comment: if u have any live api link can u share so that i can look into the working

Comment: i dont know what the hell was the problem i started a fresh install of both drupal 6 and drupal 7 and now everythng wrks fine.... may b i have messed up something in code or stuff... still thanks for reading to me :) once m done i will create a screen cast and post it here

Comment: Really glad to hear that I know how frustrating these things can be, look forward to seeing your screencast! :-)

Comment: yes... the issue is that i also installed the private taxonomy module and it is not in support for services module.... but i need something like that also i can not ignore this module as well... the taxonomies must be maintained by everyone and one can see only its own taxonomy... i knw it should be a separate question but just if u have a soln fr this as well :) thanks